# Django form fields not loading in template

Tags: python, django, forms

I can't seem to get a model form to load in my template.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    end_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.TextField()
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Event

class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['name']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import EventForm

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = EventForm()

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

index.html

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
```

I can get the form to print to the console on load when adding print(form) in views.py on the GET request, but it doesn't load in the template.

Comment: Render method you are sending events which is not defined. Also form =EventForm is unused.

Comment: Just to reinforce Vikash's point, you need to pass `form` to the template's context (in `render`) so it is available in the template. If you were using a class-based view this would be done automatically by specifying the form class.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. So my render function should be render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})?

Comment: you don't define the `events` why your code is work without errors?

Comment: @LukePhillip try it.

Comment: Sorry @Brown Bear, I had defined events but I removed it for the sake of the example. I forgot to remove it in the render. I edited the post.

Comment: @LukePhillip you tried `render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})`?

Comment: Show us your `urls.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good examples on different ways to use forms : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-view

For `index.html` to render it is expecting `form` variable. So Render method call should be like this:

```
render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I changed my render to the above, but the form still doesn't show on the template. Your answer makes great sense though, I thought that would end up being be the main problem.

Comment: that's exactly why I was avoiding posting the answer. I feared there might be multiple issues.

Comment: Nevermind, I realized I had recently inserted a typo in index.html. When I fixed that, the form showed on the template!

Comment: Great. I was just going to suggest you to try this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#more-on-fields